# Get Highest Indices of 2d Python Array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I'm using Python 2.7 and I have a 2d array like so:

1. 5.854, 7.225, 4.458, 1.834, 0.566, 0.14, 0.029, 0.005, 0.001, 0.0
2. 9.39, 11.588, 7.15, 2.941, 0.907, 0.224, 0.046, 0.008, 0.001, 0.0
3. 7.53, 9.293, 5.734, 2.359, 0.728, 0.18, 0.037, 0.007, 0.001, 0.0
4. 4.026, 4.968, 3.066, 1.261, 0.389, 0.096, 0.02, 0.003, 0.001, 0.0
5. 1.614, 1.992, 1.229, 0.506, 0.156, 0.039, 0.008, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0

And I want to get the indices of the four highest values in the array.

So list(map(max, ge)) gets me the highest values but I need the indices, so for the above data that would be [1, 1], [1, 0], [2, 1], [0, 1] and I'm not sure how to achieve this?

Comment: The suggested dupe is exactly what you need; your array is `dists` and your "highest 4" means you need to slice the `argsort` as `[-4:]` in the answer to the linked duplicate.

Comment: @PM2Ring, Are we sure OP has a numpy array?

Comment: Gary, if you aren't using Numpy (or don't want to), please let me know. I assumed you _are_ using Numpy because you used the term "array" rather than "list".

Comment: BTW, for that data, the 4 highest values and their indices are `(11.588, 1, 1), (9.39, 1, 0), (9.293, 2, 1), (7.53, 2, 0)`.

Comment: @jpp we're sure, OP literally said "2d array" and uses 2d numpy array indices.

Comment: Yes guys,not using numpy, I'm fairly new to python (from other languages) so to me an array is a list of items! :)